# How do I use the ternary operator twice in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-operator

I want to show the "a" component when updateFlage is true. Also, when I change feedboolean to true in component "a", I want to show component "b" when updateFlag is true and feedboolean is true. I used the ternary operator, but it doesn't work.

this is my code

```
<View >
<CusText/>
{updateFlag ?

    // "a"
    <View >
    <ArrowIconPickersecond      
    />
    </View>

    // "b"
    {feedboolean ? 
    (<View >
    <TextInput
    />
    </View>) : (null) }    
    :
    <CusText  />
    
    }

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to append 2 child's to ternary operator where it support single child

```
<View>
  <CusText />
  {updateFlag ? (
    // "a"
    <view>
      <View>
        <ArrowIconPickersecond />
      </View>
      // "b"
      {feedboolean ? (
        <View>
          <TextInput />
        </View>
      ) : null}{" "}
    </view>
  ) : (
    <CusText />
  )}
</View>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do something like this(replace nulls and pseudo functions with your code):

```
updateFlag ?
(
show(a),
feedboolean ? show(b) : null
)
:
null
```

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are tested and working

First Approach : Placing the "b" part within View of "a"

```
 <View >
<CusText/>
{updateFlag ?

    // "a"
    <View >
    <ArrowIconPickersecond      
    />
   // "b"
    {feedboolean ? 
    (<View >
    <TextInput
    />
    </View>) : (null) } 
    </View>

       
    :
    <CusText  />
    
    }

</View>
```

Second Approach : enclosing entirety of "a" and "b" within an empty JSX tag

```
     <View >
    <CusText/>
    {updateFlag ?
    
       <>
 // "a"
        <View >
        <ArrowIconPickersecond      
        />
       // "b"
        {feedboolean ? 
        (<View >
        <TextInput
        />
        </View>) : (null) } 
        </View>
    
</>
           
        :
        <CusText  />
        
        }
    
    </View>
```